# How to start a process using Xamarin C# on an android app?

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin, uwp, process

Having this code:

```
  Process checkForUpdates = new Process();
  checkForUpdates.StartInfo.FileName = @"python";
  checkForUpdates.StartInfo.Arguments = "-V";
  checkForUpdates.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  checkForUpdates.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  checkForUpdates.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  checkForUpdates.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
  checkForUpdates.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  checkForUpdates.Start();
  string result = checkForUpdates.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I'm trying retrieve the output of the command python -V in order to determine if python is installed on the device.

The code above compiles but the code seems to hang during the process without any errors. The same code works fine on UWP.

Is there any other way to make it work on Android?

Comment: that seems to assume that python is in the path... what if its not?

Comment: Your code will hang until the EOF is detected in standard output which will never happen until the python script terminates.  When python terminates the standard output is disposed so you get no data.  I recommend reading from StandardOutput using a different method than ReadToEnd().

Comment: If it is not in the path, Aren't I supposed to get an error stating that?
@jdweng The problem is that even if I dont read anything, the script never terminates. I have tried to use read output using checkForUpdates.OutputDataReceived += (s, er) => { Debug.WriteLine(er.Data);}; but the result is the same

Comment: Also I dont run any python script. The -V command only returns python version if installed.

Comment: There is a difference between End-Of-Stream and End-Of-File.  When you have a file opened in Windows and you get to the end of file Windows will automatically close the File/Stream And then the c# application will get an EOF.  With a stream unless the application closes the stream you will get nothing.  The position of the stream will be at the last location but you will not get any indication unless you test the position.  Windows assumes that the process that filling the stream will add more data.  To get an EOF, the python script would need to close Standard Output.

Comment: @jdweng so if I drop string result = checkForUpdates.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Won't make a difference? does the standard output still getting called by default? Since either way im getting no output at all and I cant execute code after i start the process either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I run this code inside a background worker. I put the code in a method directly inside ViewModel and it worked perfectly fine.